# What is $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left[\psi\left(1+\frac{a}{2x}\right)-\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{a}{2x}\right)\right]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, gamma-function

I need to evaluate the following limit:
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left[\psi\left(1+\frac{a}{2x}\right)-\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{a}{2x}\right)\right]$$

where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function and $a$ is a positive real number.

I started by writing
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\left[\psi\left(1+\frac{ax}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{ax}{2}\right)\right]$$
and then, using the fact that $\psi(x)\sim\ln x$ for large $x$, I got $L=0$ as the result.

However, this seems wrong to me, and [numerical trial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-polygamma%280%2C+10001%2F20000%29+%2B+polygamma%280%2C+20001%2F20000%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22+-%3E+%7B%22Math%22%7D) suggests this is the case.

Is the result I got correct or wrong? Do you know other techniques to evaluate the limit? Thank you.

Comment: For $a=1$, the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+digamma%281%2Bx%2F2%29-digamma%281%2F2%2Bx%2F2%29+from+0+to+1000) supports $L=0$. What values for $a,x$ did you use for the numerical trial? You should get [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=digamma%281%2Bx%2F2%29-digamma%281%2F2%2Bx%2F2%29%2Cx%3D10000.0) for the numerical trial.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I used $a=1$ and $x=10000$

Comment: Maple says $$\psi \left( 1+{\frac {a}{2\,x}} \right) -\psi \left( {\frac{1}{2}}+{\frac {a}{2\,x}} \right) =\frac{x}{a}-{\frac {1}{2\,{a}^{2}}}{x}^{2}+O \left({x}^{3} \right) $$ as $x \to 0^+$.  So it agrees with the answer $0$.

Comment: Note: $A \sim \ln(x)$ and $B \sim \ln(x)$ implies only $A-B = o(\ln(x))$ and does not (by itself) imply $A-B \to 0$.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you for the confirm, that was what I was unsure about

Comment: $\psi(z)\sim\ln z$ is too weak, but $\psi(z)=\ln z+O(1/z)$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote
$$I\left(\frac xa\right)=\psi\left(1+\frac{a}{2x}\right)-\psi\left(\frac12+\frac{a}{2x}\right)$$ It is convenient to use the Gauss' integral representation of  [$\psi$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

$$\psi(z)=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{e^{-t}}t-\frac{e^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}\right)dt$$
Then
$$I\left(\frac xa\right)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{at}{2x}}\big(e^\frac t2-1\big)}{e^t-1}dt=2\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-\frac{at}x}}{e^t+1}dt$$
The integrand is dominated by the integrable function $f(t)=\frac2{e^t+1}$. Therefore, based on the dominated convergence theorem we are allowed to take the limit under the integral sign and find that
$$\lim_{x\to0}I\left(\frac xa\right)=2\int_0^\infty\left(\lim_{x\to0}e^{-\frac{at}x}\right)\frac{dt}{e^t+1}=0$$
Using the presentation for  [Euler polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials) $\frac{2e^{xt}}{e^t+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}$
$$\boxed{\,\,I\left(\frac xa\right)\sim\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{E_n(0)}{n!}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{at}x}t^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac xa\right)^{n+1}E_n(0)\,\,}$$
Giving that
$$E_0(0)=1;\,E_1(0)=-\frac12;\,E_2(0)=0;\,E_3(0)=\frac14;\,E_4(0)=0;\,...$$
$$I\left(\frac xa\right)=\frac xa-\frac12\left(\frac xa\right)^2+\frac14\left(\frac xa\right)^4+O\left(\Big(\frac xa\Big)^6\right)$$